# Unable to install mysqlclient using pip3 on MacOS sierra

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, terminal

I want to use mysql in django so, trying to download mysqlclent using `$ pip3 install mysqlclient` but always this error comes up

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hb/vmtpfjk12fdcm_8l95hfqzmr0000gn/T/pip-build-pm_wn_w8/mysqlclient/
```

here are my terminal logs

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.9.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hb/vmtpfjk12fdcm_8l95hfqzmr0000gn/T/pip-build-pm_wn_w8/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/hb/vmtpfjk12fdcm_8l95hfqzmr0000gn/T/pip-build-pm_wn_w8/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/private/var/folders/hb/vmtpfjk12fdcm_8l95hfqzmr0000gn/T/pip-build-pm_wn_w8/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hb/vmtpfjk12fdcm_8l95hfqzmr0000gn/T/pip-build-pm_wn_w8/mysqlclient/
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```

indicates that you are intending to use Python3 install the package. Based on the errors in the description, I believe that MySQL maybe missing from your machine. According to [mysqlclient repo](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python), MySQLConnectorC is one of the prerequisite to run mysqlclient on OSX.

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding MySQL to your PATH :

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Comment: I tried that but still the same error is coming and it says {-bash: pip: command not found}

Comment: So it's not the same error if pip is not recognized... Are you using a virtualenv ? Is it activated ?

Comment: No i am not using virtualenv