# Problems with mysqlclient in python virtualenv on OSX

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I'm trying to make a Django application that uses mysql as database engine. I have followed a tutorial where it says I have to download pymysql packages using pip. I used the next command `pip install pymysql`. Unitl here all working. The next step is to make migrations in the django project, but when I try to do it, it throws me the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 36, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

It says my mysqlclient is in a older version, and I need to upgrade it, but when I try to install mysqlclient using `pip install mysqlclient` it throws me the next error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/8y/f31pp_9n7qvc6649ltx1fzsw0000gn/T/pip-install-94slmbbk/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/8y/f31pp_9n7qvc6649ltx1fzsw0000gn/T/pip-install-94slmbbk/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 51, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/private/var/folders/8y/f31pp_9n7qvc6649ltx1fzsw0000gn/T/pip-install-94slmbbk/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8y/f31pp_9n7qvc6649ltx1fzsw0000gn/T/pip-install-94slmbbk/mysqlclient/
```

I have tryied using `pip install --update mysqlclient` but doesn't work either. How can I solve this? I'm using python 3.7.3 and using MacOS Mojave.

Comment: mysql_config is part of [Connector/C](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/), so your python library is using the underlying C library.

Comment: and what does this mean?

Comment: `mysql_config: command not found` means Connector/C is not installed or at least not in the expected location.

Comment: and how can I install Connector/C?

Comment: By intelligently following the instructions the provided link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install mysqlclient using pip3 on MacOS sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911170/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-using-pip3-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+mysql_config+not+found